# How to read a server file and output that as a downloadable file in users web browser in XPages

Tags: java, download, xpages, output

I need to read a file (that is not available on web) on the server and output it to the user as a downloadable file.

The scenario is

1. The user click a link from an XPage
2. The request is sent to the server which reads a predefined file in the server file system
3. The file is brought back to the user as a downloadable file in the webbrowser.

The file on the server can be in any format, e.g .pdf, .exe, .doc etc

It does not matter if this is done on SSJS or in java.

I would really appreicate some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I came up with to do this, def not production code.

```
    public static byte[] grabFile(String readFile) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(readFile);
        ByteArrayOutputStream ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream ios = new FileInputStream(file);

        try {
            byte []buffer = new byte[4096];

            int read = 0;
            while ( (read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
                ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } finally { 
            try {
                 if ( ous != null ) 
                     ous.close();
            } catch ( IOException e) {
            }

            try {
                 if ( ios != null ) 
                      ios.close();
            } catch ( IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return ous.toByteArray();
    }

 public static void download() throws IOException {
        byte[] data = grabFile("\\\\server\\path\\to\\file.pdf");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.reset(); 
        response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.pdf\"");
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        output.write(data);
        output.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); 
    }
```

Then just call the download method from the beforeRenderResponse of your Xpage

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar question:

[How to stream file from xPages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468352/how-to-stream-file-from-xpages)

And here is part of the Java code taken from there and completed by me (+a fix from you!). I have now tested it also and it works:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
XspHttpServletResponse  response = (XspHttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

String strFileName = "myfile.txt";
String strFilePath= "c:" + File.separator + strFileName;
response.setContentType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(strFileName));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + strFileName);

//File file = new File(strFilePath);
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(strFilePath);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

int iLen = 0;
byte[] btBuffer = new byte[10240];  // Not sure about optimal buffer size
while ((iLen = fileIn.read(btBuffer)) != -1) {
  out.write(btBuffer, 0, iLen);
}

facesContext.responseComplete();
out.close();
```

You could do all this in SSJS also.

If `guessContentTypeFromName` does not guess it then you need to modify the definition file on server. Or if you have a limited set of file types you can place the MIME-type table in your code/application.

Comment: could you please put together a complete script, I could not get it working. I get file not found

Comment: I try to do later today. Meanwhile it's probably a good idea to check that your file path and name are correct :-)

Comment: thank you, how do I resolve the source error with getFacesContext()? 
tried this 
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
XspHttpServletResponse  response = (XspHttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
 but then I get file not found whe nrunning

Comment: Yes, looks like the code in the linked answer was meant to be run from servlet. I think your code is correct (updated that to my answer). Check that the account running the code (System?) has access to the file. Also try with a simple one line code if you can open any file from Java.

Comment: Panu, I had to choose only one answer to be correct so I choosed Toby as he had the final missing pieces to get it solved. but your code was really helpful too so I gave you a vote for it.

Comment: Great that it's working. What was the problem causing "File not found"?

Comment: well, I really don't know what caused file not found. anyway, I got it working locally, but still get error 500 when trying on server so I have a few steps left. I will probably share it somewhere when it is ready

Comment: OK, I've actually done this in SSJS and if you still have problems I can find the SSJS code and post it.

Comment: I posted as snippet http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dispay-and-download-any-files-from-the-server-file-system

Comment: OK good. Finally I had time to test the code I posted (with fixes from you!). It works perfectly. So I'm not sure what were the "missing pieces". The missing piece in Toby's code is that the MIME type is hard coded to PDF (you needed a solution for "any format"). Also the file separator is hard coded so his code will probably not work in Unix-based OS.